# MySQL UPDATE statement not locking row as expected

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I have a table where every row represents a resource that can be used by a consumer. The resource can only be used by one consumer at any time. The consumer selects the available resources and randomly picks one. In order to make sure that consumer can use the resource it picked, I have the following SQL statement: `UPDATE resource SET is_in_use=1 WHERE is_in_use=0 AND id=?`

If rows affected = 1, I assumed it would mean the consumer has exclusive use of the resource. Not so. I occasionally have situations where more than one consumer is assigned to a single resource.

The full php code:

```
public function useResource() {
    $mysqli = secureMysqli();
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE resource SET is_in_use=1 WHERE is_in_use=0 AND id=?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->id);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If you changed the `is_in_use` field from a flag to a "consumer_id" of some sort, you could recheck the value after the update to confirm. (Also, `resource.id` is a unique or primary key, right?)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the complete answer you are looking for but there are some improvements to your code. Give the following a try:

```
public function useResource() {
    $mysqli = secureMysqli();
    // add `` backticks around table and column names to prevent mysql reserved words error
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `resource` SET `is_in_use` = 1 WHERE `is_in_use` = 0 AND `id` = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->id);
        $stmt->execute(); // No need to check if is executed.

        if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

If you do want to check if your query is correctly executed add:

```
if( !$stmt){
  echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

You can add this right under every `$stmt` call so also under the prepare, bind and execute statements